# Trouble understanding this image creation algorithm

Tags: python, opencv

The output image is this:
[image]

Where you can control the angle between the drawn lines, the line of code I can´t understand is this one:

```
indice = ((matriz >= n*angulo) & (matriz < (n+1)*angulo))
```

Function:

```
def createImage(angulo):
    #Image height and width

    w ,h = (100,100)

    #Image array
    img = np.zeros((w, h), np.uint8)
    cor = 255

    x,y = np.meshgrid(range(0,w),range(0,h))

    centerX = int(w/2)
    centerY = int(h/2)

    #Coordinates in relation to center of image
    x = x-centerX
    y = y-centerY

    #Complex coordinates
    matriz = x+1j*y

    matriz =np.angle(matriz)*180/np.pi

    for n in range(int(-360/angulo), int(360/angulo)):

        indice = ((matriz >= n*angulo) & (matriz < (n+1)*angulo))

        img[indice] = cor

        cor = 0 if cor == 255 else 255

    cv2.imshow("star" , img)
    cv2.imwrite("star.png" , img)
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This line appears to create an index mask, that is an array that can be used to extract a part of an array or matrix where a particular condition holds. 
The condition used is:

```
((matriz >= n*angulo) & (matriz < (n+1)*angulo))
```

which uses bitwise operator `&`. This operator returns `1` if both operands evaluate to `1` and `0` otherwise. 
This means your index map will have a `1` value in locations where 
values of `matriz` are between `n * angulo` and `(n+1) * angulo`. 
Accessing `matriz` with this index map would give you an array containing exactly those values. Subequently, it is used to extract a part of image `img`. Each subsequent extracted part is colored in all black or all white (pixel values of `0` and `255` respectively).

Answer (score 0):

Part of the magic happens outside the loop.  Add some debug output help you visualize this.  use a smaller matrix like 5x5 and large angulo value make output easier to read:

> ```
> matriz = x+1j*y 
> # create a complex plane
> print(matriz)
>
> matriz =np.angle(matriz)*180/np.pi 
> # convert each point from x/y coordinate to their angle from x-axis
> print(matriz)
>
> for n in range(int(-360/angulo), int(360/angulo)):
>     indice = ((matriz >= n*angulo) & (matriz < (n+1)*angulo))
>     # select all the points that falls between n*angulo and (n+1)*angulo
>     print(indice)
> ...
> ```